# How to include a preamble file in a main file

Tags: templates, include

I have a main01.tex file for a training course with a pretty big pre-amble.
I have a main02.tex file for another training course with the same pretty big pre-amble.
I have a main03.tex file for yet another training course with the same pretty big pre-amble.
All of them or 'under construction'.
Each main contains its own \include{chapter_X}

These preambles get updated still quite often (I'm still learning LaTeX). But now I have to update 3 mainxx.tex file each time I find some new interesting \newcommand or \package I need to use (which I want to use in all of my courses).
How can I do this?

PS: the mainxx.tex files all have their own folder, but for the new main-preamble I could use 1 default "template"folder...

Comment: Welcome. // Use \input{} , not \include{}, for the preamble AFTER \documentclass.

Comment: (are you sure you should have a "big preamble" (most templates that include lots of files are a bad idea, it's better just to include packages that you use) but anyway put all the shared code in `mypackages.sty` in a directory in your input path eg `~/texmf/tex/latex/mypackages/mypackages.sty` by default and then your documents just need `\usepackage{mypackages}`